# PowerCLI Inventory Script Getting extra Characters

Tags: vmware, inventory, powercli

I am working on a Inventory Script for my environment.  The main Driving reason for this, i want to use tags to assign vm's to a sys admin, and a business owner.  I have created a category call sysadmin, and BusinessOwner.  The Category is set to one tag per object.

The script i have built seems to work fine but i get extra characters in the tag related columns, and in uptime.

in the Sysadmin Tag the data looks like: @{Tag=SysAdmin/ITOps: John Smith}

i would like it to look like: ITOps: John Smith

in Uptime the data looks like: "@{Days=9}"

i would like it to look like: 9

i also tried removing the | Select Tag option from the "$row.sysadmin" line. The data is formatted differently: [SysAdmin/ITOps: John Smith] SERVERNAME

This is a little better, but it sill has garbage Characters in it.

I attempted to use .trim, but perhaps im using it wrong.  any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

*Note i have intentionally disabled the DC/Cluster Sections for testing against a folder

*Note: The original script was obtained from http://www.vstrong.info/2014/03/25/export-vcenter-virtual-machine-inventory/

```
$report = @()
#foreach ($DC in Get-Datacenter -Name MyDC){ # Specify Datacenter name if needed
#foreach ($Cluster in Get-Cluster -Location $DC ){ # Specify Cluster name if needed
foreach ($VM in Get-VM -Location Tag_test){

$row = "" | select DC, Cluster, ResourcePool, VMPath, VMhost, PowerState, Name, OS, IPaddress, MacAddress, CPU, Memory, ProvisionedSpaceGB, UsedSpaceGB, Datastore, Notes, Tools, Sysadmin, BusinessOwner, snapshots, portgroup, uptime

  $row.DC = $DC
  $row.Cluster = $Cluster
     ##### If there is no Resource Pool configured in the Cluster, use the Cluster name
     if ($vm.ResourcePool -like "Resources") {$row.ResourcePool = $Cluster}
     else {$row.ResourcePool = $vm.ResourcePool}
        ##### Full VM path in the vCenter VM folder structure - start
        $current = $vm.Folder
        $path = $vm.Name
        do {
        $parent = $current
        if($parent.Name -ne "vm"){$path =  $parent.Name + "\" + $path}
        $current = Get-View $current.Parent
        } while ($current.Parent -ne $null)
        $row.VMPath = $path
        ##### Full VM path in the vCenter VM folder structure - finish
  $row.VMhost = $vm.VMHost
  $row.PowerState = $vm.PowerState
  $row.Name = $vm.Name
  $row.OS = $vm.Guest.OSFullName
  $row.IPaddress = $vm.Guest.IPAddress | Out-String
  $row.MacAddress =($vm | Get-NetworkAdapter).MacAddress -join ", ";  
  $row.CPU = $vm.NumCPU
  $row.Memory = $vm.MemoryGb
  $row.ProvisionedSpaceGB = [math]::round( $vm.ProvisionedSpaceGB , 2 )
  $row.UsedSpaceGB = [math]::round( $vm.UsedSpaceGB , 2 )
  #$row.Datastore = ($vm | Get-Datastore).Name | Out-String
  $row.Datastore =  (Get-Datastore -vm $vm) -split ", " -join ", "; 
  $row.Notes = $vm.Notes
  $row.tools = $vm.ExtensionData.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus
  $row.sysadmin = Get-TagAssignment -Entity $vm -Category SysAdmin| Select Tag 
  $row.Businessowner = Get-TagAssignment -Entity $vm -Category BusinessOwner | Select Tag 
  $row.snapshots = ($vm | get-snapshot).count;
  $row.portgroup = ($vm | Get-NetworkAdapter).NetworkName -join ", ";  
  $uptime = get-stat -entity $vm -stat sys.uptime.latest -RealTime -MaxSamples 1
  $row.uptime = new-timespan -seconds $uptime.value |Select Days 
$report += $row

}

$report | Sort Name | Export-Csv -Path "D:\VMs.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out, it might not be the most graceful, but i used placeholder variables to make the extra data "@{Days=" to remove from the report.

Hopefully this script is helpful for people

```
VSphere Inventory Script With VSphere Tag Support.

Connect-VIServer vcenter.server.name


$report = @()

foreach ($DC in Get-Datacenter ){ # Specify Datacenter name if needed
foreach ($Cluster in Get-Cluster -Location $DC ){ # Specify Cluster name if needed
foreach ($VM in Get-VM -Location $Cluster | where-object {$_.Folder -notmatch "Template Base"}  ){


$row = "" | select Name, PowerState, OS, Tools, Notes, Sysadmin, BusinessOwner, Snapshots, Uptime, DC, Cluster, ResourcePool, VMPath, VMhost, IPaddress, MacAddress, PortGroup, CPU, Memory, ProvisionedSpaceGB, UsedSpaceGB, Datastore
#Null Out Variables
$ipadd = $null
$macadd = $null
$maclist = $null
$portlist = $null
    $row.Name = $vm.Name
    $row.PowerState = $vm.PowerState
    $row.OS = $vm.Guest.OSFullName
    $row.Tools = $vm.ExtensionData.Guest.ToolsVersionStatus
    $row.Notes = $vm.Notes
    #This Section Queries for the Sysadmin Tag Value
        $sysadmin = Get-TagAssignment -Entity $vm -Category SysAdmin
    $row.Sysadmin = $sysadmin.tag
    #This Section Queries for the BusinessOwner Tag Value
        $Businessowner = Get-TagAssignment -Entity $vm -Category BusinessOwner
    $row.Businessowner = $Businessowner.tag
    $row.Snapshots = ($vm | get-snapshot).count;
    #This Section Calculates System Uptime
        $uptime = get-stat -entity $vm -stat sys.uptime.latest -RealTime -MaxSamples 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $uptimed = new-timespan -seconds $uptime.value
    $row.Uptime = $uptimed.days
    $row.DC = $DC
    $row.Cluster = $Cluster
     ##### If there is no Resource Pool configured in the Cluster, use the Cluster name
     if ($vm.ResourcePool -like "Resources") {$row.ResourcePool = $Cluster}
     else {$row.ResourcePool = $vm.ResourcePool}
        ##### Full VM path in the vCenter VM folder structure - start
        $current = $vm.Folder
        $path = $vm.Name
        do {
        $parent = $current
        if($parent.Name -ne "vm"){$path =  $parent.Name + "\" + $path}
        $current = Get-View $current.Parent
        } while ($current.Parent -ne $null)
    $row.VMPath = $path
        ##### Full VM path in the vCenter VM folder structure - finish
    $row.VMhost = $vm.VMHost
    #$row.IPaddress = $vm.Guest.IPAddress | Out-String
    #Get all IP's and Make a list
        $iplist =$vm.Guest.IPAddress 
        Foreach ($ip in $iplist) { $ipadd += $ip + "; "}
    $row.IPaddress = $ipadd
    #Get all MAC's and Make a list
    #$row.MacAddress =($vm | Get-NetworkAdapter).MacAddress -join ", ";  
        $maclist =($vm | Get-NetworkAdapter)|Select MacAddress
        Foreach ($mac in $maclist) { $macadd += $mac.macaddress + "; "}
    $row.MacAddress = $macadd
    #$row.portgroup = ($vm | Get-NetworkAdapter).NetworkName -join ", ";
    #Get all Port Groups's and Make a list
        $portgroup =$vm | Get-NetworkAdapter
        Foreach ($port in $portgroup) { $portlist += $port.networkname + "; "}
    $row.PortGroup = $portlist
    $row.CPU = $vm.NumCPU
    $row.Memory = $vm.MemoryGb
    $row.ProvisionedSpaceGB = [math]::round( $vm.ProvisionedSpaceGB , 2 )
    $row.UsedSpaceGB = [math]::round( $vm.UsedSpaceGB , 2 )
    #$row.Datastore = ($vm | Get-Datastore).Name | Out-String
    $row.Datastore =  (Get-Datastore -vm $vm) -split ", " -join ", ";

$report += $row

}}}


$mailfrom = "from@email.com"
$mailto = "to@email.com"
$smtpserver = "smpt.server.com"
$csvpath = "C:\pcli\Scheduled_Scripts\Production_VMs_ $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
$report | Sort Name | Export-Csv -Path $csvpath -NoType
Send-MailMessage -From $mailfrom -to $mailto -subject "Production VM Inventory" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -body "See Attachment" -Attachments $csvpath
Attachment" -Attachments $csvpath


Remove-Item $csvpath
```